# Primitive function tricks

Tags: integration

Calculation [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l27wdeid93yx4fb/Screenshot%202014-04-16%2013.07.47.png)

Questions:

- how did he get the idea to "split up" $r^2$ into $2r \cdot r/2$?
- is he doing integration by parts after the second = sign? I can't really follow the algebra here.

Comment: but f'/f is the case when we use ln(f) as primitive

Answer (score 2):

He got the idea because he had a $(1 + r^2)$-like thing in the denominator, and wanted to substitute $u = 1 + r^2$, and that would involve $du = 2dr$. So he threw in a $2$ and $ 1/2$ to make it simpler.

Personally, I'd do the substitution by $u = 1 + r^2$ and $ (1/2) du = dr$, so that the $(1/2)$ would appear naturally, but that would have taken another line of algebra, I guess.

Of course, he didn't actually do the substitution right there, either. As you've guessed, he's doing integration by parts; the first factor is $f'$ and the second $(r/2)$ is $g$; he replaces this with $fg - \int f ~g'$. You might want to do out the algebra in the int-by-parts for yourself to double-check it.